# react and vue projects with less files?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, file

This may sound like a strange question, but I come from an emacs,xterm background and I am used to work a few files and have total control of what I am doing.

Now, I am going to learn react and vue, but when I examine the number of files that are generated for a project with:

`npx create-react-app`

`vue create app`

then it adds upp to 36000 for react and 19000 for vue. That is something that annoys me. Is there any way to create a project in both framework that has significally less files?

Comment: 99.9% of that is probably in `node_modules`, which you won't be messing with.

Comment: Just ignore the node_modules folder on your .gitignore. There is where all the external modules are installed. Just run 'npm install' when you want to replicate your solution in another environment.

Comment: Welcome to the world of dependency management. The problem is not specific to JS but is prominent in its ecosystem. You aren't supposed to have direct control over these files so this urge is the first thing you can fix. You may want to pick project deps carefully in order to not make it slow to install, but that's all. There are dep managers like Yarn 2 that allow to avoid this but you shouldn't consider this way until you're a seasoned JS dev because its use is way outside normal scenario of frontend framework usage and will inevitably leave you with solving related problems alone.

Comment: thanks for the responses. Yeah, those numbers reflect node_modules. But there is something inherenlty wrong (in my view) when there is a need of 36000 files for a simple hello world app. 
I like chez scheme and that sort of succintly syntax. but thats just me.

Comment: @JonasFredriksson You can check for node_modules meme for some background. But basically this is what you get with a premade universal setup that these commands provide. Both React and Vue promote non-spec compliant things (JSX and .vue SFC), you need extra tools to work with them, or not use these things and limit yourself. You can end up with a much sleeker setup for hello world or small app but this requires extra man-hours and advanced JS ecosystem skills, and you may still need to add heavy deps later depending on the tasks, so focusing on 36000 files would be a waste of time

Comment: @JonasFredriksson If you want a "simple hello world app", `document.write('Hello world')`. You don't need React or Vue for that. You install React or Vue if you intend to write *more* than "hello world" at some point, and the contents of `node_modules` are intended to support that.

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is scaffolding. You do not require scaffolding to use vue.

You are also using build components to minify JS code and include all types of things such as fall backs.

If you want to learn it from scratch you can start with the CDN version then move onto learning to use the templating engines and so on.

If you really want to start to learn things from scratch.

1. Use CDN Versions
2. Learn Rollup.js
3. Learn Vue

Comment: More precisely, Rollup+Babel+Vue plugin.